# Symfony crash course

Tags: php, symfony1

Can you guys provide some good tutorials on symfony? Simple stuff, nothing really big and well-detailed, like the Jobeet tutorial. A crash course, maybe some video tutorials too.

Comment: I know jobeet takes a while to work through, but it really is a good way to get to know the features of symphony.

Comment: Are there any good video-tutorials?

Comment: Which version? Symfony 1.x or Symfony 2?

Comment: 1. or 2, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with the [Getting Started](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_2/en/01-Introduction) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the Jobeet tutorials, the other tutorials you will find online will deal mostly with specifics.  If you want an introduction to the framework, there is no better documentation than the ones provided by sensio labs.

http://www.symfony-project.org/doc/1_4/

Another good resource, is the #symfony channel on Freenode.  If you have any questions, that channel is quite active and helpful.